# Replace one character with another character in a string

Tags: c#, replace

Here is some basic simple code, where I want to process a `string`. Due to my requirements I have to replace a `.` with a `,` so that the further `string` to `double` parsing will work. For *some reason* the `.`s don't get replaced.
Sample code:

```
string[] pointArray = "3066.4735709236,4659.65039509825".Trim().Split(',');

foreach (var point in pointArray)
{
    point.Replace('.',',');
}

//just checking for `.` in those strings
//a MessageBox pops up, because there are still `.` in the strings

Array.ForEach(pointArray, foo => { foo.Contains('.'); MessageBox.Show("has been not replaced"); });
```

What do I overlook?

Comment: Strings are immutable.  `Replace` returns a new string with the change

Comment: Ok I got it, thank you. What a dumb mistake... . So basically `point = point.Replace('.',',');` solves the issue. Will put that in a `for` loop though.

Comment: Seems like I should stop working for today...

Comment: Also, you can parse the string '3066.47' as a double by specifying your cultureinfo when converting a string to a double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] pointArray = "3066.4735709236,4659.65039509825".Trim().Split(',');

for (int i = 0; i < pointArray.Length; i++)
{
    pointArray[i] = pointArray[i].Replace('.',',');
}
```

String are **immutable**, you have to set the value.

(Just a note, you have to use a for loop, because foreach doesn't allow `item` ti be modified.)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your source string to doubles array with `linq`:

```
var srcString = "3066.4735709236,4659.65039509825";
var doubles = srcString
    .Trim()
    .Split(',')
    .SelectMany(s => s.Split('.').Select(double.Parse))
    .ToArray();
```

This code will split your string by `,` then by `.` and convert each substring to double